# Subsetting a data.frame column to a vector for making a confint

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a data.frame and I need to subset one column from the `data.frame` and make a vector from it in order to create a `confint` from the vector.

I am able to subset the column, but if I create the vector by `vector<-as.vector(data.frame$column)`, then I am not able to do confint because there is an error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Dataframe example:

```
origin MPG
1       20.5
1       18
2       15
2       25
3       31
etc.    etc.
```

I want to make a confidence interval for the miles per gallon variable according to the origin of the car (US=1, EU=2, JPN=3).

Thanks for advance for any help with this issue.

Cheers.

Comment: `confint` takes a fitted model object as argument andn ot a vector. So you have to create this object, certainly from the vector, and pass this object to `confint`. By the way your question is not reproducible, please add an example of the data.frame and describe what you are going to achieve (why a confidence interval?)

Comment: But I just found out I can make t.test straight from the dataset, so I guess problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

`confint` computes a confidence interval for a fitted model, not for a population parameter. (see `help(confint)` arguments section : `object: a fitted model object.`) You can compute the interval using its formula like this :

```
set.seed(50)
x <- rnorm(100)
mean(x)
[1] -0.1135271
sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
[1] 0.09926079
```